# magit log with more complex glob pattern for --remotes argument

Tags: magit

I want to add a custom log option via (in init.el after some require magit package introduction):

```
(defun magit-log-my-stuff (&optional args files)
  (interactive (magit-log-arguments))
  "Show log for all my relevant stuff."
  (magit-log-setup-buffer
   (list "--branches" "--remotes={myremote/foo/[ao]*,otherremote/bar/x*}")
   args files))

(transient-append-suffix 'magit-log "l"
  '("m" "mystuff" magit-log-my-stuff))
```

Everything works as expected if I add a single glob pattern like "--remotes=myremote/foo/[ao]*", but not with the "or" {...,...} glob pattern. On the command line, I get the expected if I use

```
git log --branches --remotes={myremote/foo/[ao]*,otherremote/bar/x*}
```

So it seems that somehow emacs/magit provides slightly different arguments to git log. How can I provide such a more complex glob pattern in magit?

Comment: What does the magit process log show as the executed command?

Comment: I have tried to figure that out, but the magit process log (via $) does not show any git log command, only some other git commands. Seems this is done differently somehow. I also enabled magit-toggle-git-debug, but nothing is shown. If "HEAD" is present in the list of branches (as is the case for some options like local branches in magit-log.el), then I get "git … rev-parse --short HEAD\~ \newline fatal: Needed a single revision".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather simple, just provide several --remotes options:

```
(defun magit-log-my-stuff (&optional args files)
  (interactive (magit-log-arguments))
  "Show log for all my relevant stuff."
  (magit-log-setup-buffer
   (list "--branches" "--remotes=myremote/foo/[ao]*" "--remotes=otherremote/bar/x*")
   args files))
```

In fact, on the command line the shell (bash) resolves the glob pattern argument

```
--remotes={myremote/foo/[ao]*,otherremote/bar/x*}
```

as

```
'--remotes=myremote/foo/[ao]*' '--remotes=otherremote/bar/x*'
```

which is what is passed on to git log.